# Selenium via Eclipse: is it possible to move the cursor position?

Tags: selenium, eclipse-plugin, cursor

I am using the selenium plug in for eclipse to automate the testing of newly created websites. I am trying to click a button that is in a menu and only visible when the cursor is located over the menu.

Is it possible to move the cursor so that this button can be clicked ?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend a little on how the menu has been implemented (i.e. the event that will trigger your button to appear) but you should look at the `focus` and `mouseOver` methods for selenium.

I.e. do something like

```
this.selenium.mouseOver(element);
```

where `element` refers to the menu and then do a `click` on the button.  If `mouseOver` does not work (i.e. the button does not become available) try `focus` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you're using Selenium RC or Selenium 2 and WebDriver.

I can only speak to the latter, but you can use Actions to move the mouse and click.  The basic idea is you define an object that is a series of actions, and then you perform those actions.

An introduction on how to use these is at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions, and a good writeup with Python examples is http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2011/selenium-advanced-user-interactions.html

It sounds like in your case, you would have something like:

```
Actions menuClick = new Actions(driver);

builder.MoveToElement(menuElement)
    .MoveToElement(buttonElement)
    .click(buttonElement)

Action menuClick = builder.build();

menuClick.perform();
```